# Java- finding an index in a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexof

I have a 2D Array of mostly consecutive integers.  I want to take a user's integer input and locate the index of the integer one less than the user's input.

I have manually declared the first two columns in my array, and the remaining twelve columns are randomly assigned integers from a different array.

```
public static int[][] board = new int[4][14];

  public static int[][] deal(int[] cards) {


    board[0][0] = 1;
    board[0][1] = 0;
    board[1][0] = 14;
    board[1][1] =0;
    board[2][0] = 27;
    board[2][1] = 0;
    board[3][0] = 40;
    board[3][1] = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            board[i][j + 2] = cards[j + (i * 12)];
        }

    } return board;

}
```

I am trying to locate the integer one smaller than the users input and if the following integer (in the same row) is a 0, swap the 0 and the user's input. 
I realize there is not a built in function indexOf for an array the following code will not run.

```
 public static int[][] move(int[][] board) {

    int input;
    int place =0;
    if(board.indexOf(input-1) +1 == 0){
        place =board.indexOf(input);
        board.indexOf(input) = 0;
        board.indexOf(input-1) +1 = place;
    }
    return board;

}
```

Comment: What if it's the last element in the row?

Comment: @shmosel do you mean the input or the or the input-1.  If you mean the input-1 than the if statement should be false since there isn’t a 0 after input-1.

Comment: When you say "swap", you mean you want to capture the value before replacing it?

Comment: @shmosel The program should take the integer the user inputs, find that integer in the game, and then move that integer to the position of the 0 and move the 0 to the previous position of the integer.

Comment: Now I'm totally confused.

Comment: @shmosel The game is basically taking a deck of cards and making 4 rows. Then inserting a yellow card into a row somewhere.  If the card preceding the yellow card (zero in my code) is a 2 than the user can select a 3 from any of the rows and switch its place with the yellow card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use the index of function, you need to switch into List(i.e. ArrayList, Vector etc) of lists . Then you code will be like this

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> deal(int[] cards) {
   ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> board = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
   for(int  i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       board.add(new ArrayList<Integer>);
   }
   board.get(0).add(1);
   board.get(0).add(0);
   board.get(1).add(14);
   board.get(1).add(0);
   board.get(2).add(27);
   board.get(2).add(0);
   board.get(3).add(40);
   board.get(3).add(0);

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
         board.get(i).add(cards[j + (i * 12)]);
     }
   } 
  return board;
}
```

Another thing you can do(and which is better because Lists have their overhead in performance) is write your own indexOf() function like below which return an array of integers because in a 2D array index means two integers(row and col):

```
int[] indexOf(int [] [] ar, int row, int col, int x) { //this function will find x in 2D array ar(with dimension of row*col) and return the index
   int [] index = new int [2];
   index [0] = index[1] = -1; 
   for(int i = 0; i<row; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<col; j++) {
            if(ar[i][j] == x) {
               index[0] = i;
               index[1] = j;
               return index;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: I have considered using an ArrayList but was told the integers will be converted to methods.  Since I am doing arithmetic with the values I don't know if an Array List is usable.

Comment: To keep the integer in ArrayList you may use Integer instead of int, but this shouldn't create problem because java has a Autoboxing and Unboxing mechanism, follow this link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html . You can do the arithmetic operations on Integer just like int.